# From inequality to supremum

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory

I am trying to follow the derivation of a lower bound on mutual information given in [1].

At first the following is stated:
\begin{aligned} K L(P, Q) &=E_{z \sim P} \ln \frac{P(z)}{Q(z)} \\ &=E_{z \sim P} \ln \left(\frac{G(z)}{Q(z)} \frac{P(z)}{G(z)}\right) \\ &=E_{z \sim P} \ln \frac{G(z)}{Q(z)}+K L(P, G) \\ & \geq E_{z \sim P} \ln \frac{G(z)}{Q(z)} \end{aligned}

And then it is noted that equality of the above inequality is achieved for G(z) = P(z) and hence we have:

\begin{aligned}
K L(P, Q)=\sup _{G} E_{z \in P} \ln \frac{G(z)}{Q(z)}
\end{aligned}

It is however not completely clear to me how one can reformulate the above inequality to this formulation using the supremum.

[1] https://arxiv.org/pdf/1811.04251.pdf equation (1)

Comment: The inequality holds for all possible $G$, therefore $KL(P,Q)$ is greater or equal than the $\sup$. But with $G(z) = P(z)$ the inequality is achieved, so it has to be less than or equal to the $\sup$. This both facts give the equality, isn't it? I'm not too knowleadgeable about this notation though, so maybe I'm missing something here.